# Using Routing in Asp.Net Webform Application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, system.web.routing

I am using `System.Web.Routing` in the Asp.Net Webform Application. I wrote the following route in the `global.asax`

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; // I made true/false both, but none works

routes.Add("competition", new Route
            (
               "Test",
               new CustomRouteHandler("~/Test/WebForm1.aspx")
            ));
```

And the directory structure is the following:-

> Application
>
> |
>
> |--- Test (Folder)
>
> ```
>    |--- Webform1.aspx
> ```

When I write in the browser `http://localhost:xxxx/Test/` (using Casini), the request is handle in the traditional manner not through the routes, and, it gives me the "Directory Listing -- /test/" page.

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I chose the pragmatic solution that the file that should handle the default path is called Default.aspx

```
routes.Add("competition", new Route ( "Test", new CustomRouteHandler("~/Test/Default.aspx") ));
```

Comment: Indeed, or use Default.aspx instead as suggested since its probably already in the defalt docuemtns list

Comment: @Pete : The suggestions you provided work with me too. But, now the question is which http Module is executing this request, the traditional http Module (asp.net one ) or routing http modules (asp.net mvc)? Because, a/c to the rememdy, i think its using traditional http module (asp.net one).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Routing straight out the box for WebForms, I have just implemented this for "WebForms" specifically, since there is some things to be aware of:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx

HTH

**Update:**

Using the implementation in the link still produces the same error, since the actual folder exists.

I would think that since the folder exists, it would be served (in some cases listing the folder contents may be desired)

Maybe taking a different approach would be better for instance, if the pages all point to specific extranet login pages maybe an extra descriptive folder would work, eg: /Extranets/Test/  ?

Comment: Yes, i am using straight out of the box. All the other routes are working fine, such as 
routes.Add("competitionNew", new Route ( "NewTest", new CustomRouteHandler("~/Test/WebForm1.aspx") ));

But, my real concern is, if the request is http://localhost:xxx/Test/ where Test is also the folder in the application, then it is showing the "Directory Listing -- /test/" page, not rendering the webform1 page.

Comment: ok, tested on my app (with WebForm routing as per link implemented) and ot appears to do the same thing, I have updated my answer...

Comment: ...if you set the default document in iis to WebForm1.aspx, it would serve that page, but maybe not desired in your app?